# Email client which supports multiple account and 1 archive per account

Tags: windows, email-client

I am looking for a Windows desktop email client, compatible with Windows 7 and 10 (64 bit) which supports the following

1. Multiple email accounts
2. Pop3, IMAP
3. Signatures
4. Scripting (such as VBa, but any language)
5. 1 archive per account, and automated archiving

Outlook seems to do the lot, other than point 5 (which is where my issue is). Outlok appears to want to archive all accounts to a single folder.

Comment: With a custom filter Outlook can store mails from different accounts in different folders or even in different data files. I don't have it handy right now, but I'll post a more serious answer when I can get a more detailed look at it.

Comment: @Alejandro, if you know a solution for Outlook it may be better to post it http://superuser.com/questions/968667/how-to-create-different-archives-for-each-email-account-in-outlook